# Vue: initial triggering of a computed property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

In my Vue component, I have a computed property which watches the state and the component, and returns an object.

```
        currentOrganization () {
            if (this.$store.state.organizations && this.selectedOrganization) {
                return this.$store.state.organizations.filter(org => org.id === this.selectedOrganization)[0];
            }
        }
```

Unfortunately, this property does not update automatically when the component loads, though I can see that I have both `this.$store.state.organizations` and `this.selectedOrganization`. It does, however, update when I dispatch an action to my Vuex store via the select component below:

```
                <b-form-select id="orgSelect"
                               v-model="selectedOrganization"
                               :options="this.$store.state.organizations.map(org => {return {value: org.id, text:org.name}})"
                               size="sm"
                               v-on:input="currentOrganizationChange()"
                               class="w-75 mb-3">
                    <template slot="first">
                        <option :value="null" disabled>Change Organization</option>
                    </template>
                </b-form-select>
```

The component dispatches a Vuex action:

```
            currentOrganizationChange () {
                this.$store.dispatch('setCurrentOrganization', this.selectedOrganization);
            },
```

How can I make `currentOrganization()` compute initially?

Answer (score 4):

The computed will not calculate until you use it.

`console.log` it, or just write current organization; somewhere in code which executes and it will calculate :)

Comment: Well, that's dumb. I mean, from Vue's perspective. Thanks!

Comment: why "best answer" was removed? :'(

Comment: Because it turns out that the issue was more complicated. ```typeof this.selectedOrganization``` turns out to be "string." On the first run, ```currentOrganization()``` returns `null`, since nothing meets the filter conditions. On subsequent runs, it seems to coerce `this.selectedOrganization` to an integer, and returns results.

Comment: could you make fiddle?

Comment: it is possible that `b-form-select` emits initial null-value that breaks `selectedOrganization`. Could you try an ordinary <select> instead?

Comment: I've fixed it by just doing `parseInt()` in `currentOrganization()`

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ there was not enough information in question for answer

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure that your computed always returns a value. A linter would have warned you of that error. Chances are your condition is failing -- perhaps `this.selectedOrganization` is falsy.